# paytm payment gateway with php getChecksumFromString function not working with local

Tags: php, paytm

In pg redirects file its show me 500 when i call payment with sandbox credential and show me session expired error.

All code getting from https://github.com/Paytm-Payments/Paytm_Web_Sample_Kit_PHP

config_paytm.php

```
    <?php
/*

- Use PAYTM_ENVIRONMENT as 'PROD' if you wanted to do transaction in production environment else 'TEST' for doing transaction in testing environment.
- Change the value of PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY constant with details received from Paytm.
- Change the value of PAYTM_MERCHANT_MID constant with details received from Paytm.
- Change the value of PAYTM_MERCHANT_WEBSITE constant with details received from Paytm.
- Above details will be different for testing and production environment.

*/
define('PAYTM_ENVIRONMENT', 'TEST'); // PROD
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY', 'bKMfNxPPf_QdZppa'); //Change this constant's value with Merchant key downloaded from portal
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_MID', 'DIY12386817555501617'); //Change this constant's value with MID (Merchant ID) received from Paytm
define('PAYTM_MERCHANT_WEBSITE', 'DIYtestingweb'); //Change this constant's value with Website name received from Paytm

$PAYTM_DOMAIN = "pguat.paytm.com";
if (PAYTM_ENVIRONMENT == 'PROD') {
    $PAYTM_DOMAIN = 'secure.paytm.in';
}

define('PAYTM_REFUND_URL', 'https://'.$PAYTM_DOMAIN.'/oltp/HANDLER_INTERNAL/REFUND');
define('PAYTM_STATUS_QUERY_URL', 'https://'.$PAYTM_DOMAIN.'/oltp/HANDLER_INTERNAL/TXNSTATUS');
define('PAYTM_STATUS_QUERY_NEW_URL', 'https://'.$PAYTM_DOMAIN.'/oltp/HANDLER_INTERNAL/getTxnStatus');
define('PAYTM_TXN_URL', 'https://'.$PAYTM_DOMAIN.'/oltp-web/processTransaction');

?>
```

pg_redirect.php

```
    <?php
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

// following files need to be included
require_once("./lib/config_paytm.php");
require_once("./lib/encdec_paytm.php");

$checkSum = "";
$paramList = array();

$ORDER_ID = $_POST["ORDER_ID"];
$CUST_ID = $_POST["CUST_ID"];
$INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID = $_POST["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"];
$CHANNEL_ID = $_POST["CHANNEL_ID"];
$TXN_AMOUNT = $_POST["TXN_AMOUNT"];

// Create an array having all required parameters for creating checksum.
$paramList["MID"] = PAYTM_MERCHANT_MID;
$paramList["ORDER_ID"] = $ORDER_ID;
$paramList["CUST_ID"] = $CUST_ID;
$paramList["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = $INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID;
$paramList["CHANNEL_ID"] = $CHANNEL_ID;
$paramList["TXN_AMOUNT"] = $TXN_AMOUNT;
$paramList["WEBSITE"] = PAYTM_MERCHANT_WEBSITE;

/*
$paramList["MSISDN"] = $MSISDN; //Mobile number of customer
$paramList["EMAIL"] = $EMAIL; //Email ID of customer
$paramList["VERIFIED_BY"] = "EMAIL"; //
$paramList["IS_USER_VERIFIED"] = "YES"; //

*/

//Here checksum string will return by getChecksumFromArray() function.
$checkSum = getChecksumFromString($paramList,PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY);
//print_r($checkSum);

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Merchant Check Out Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center><h1>Please do not refresh this page...</h1></center>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo PAYTM_TXN_URL ?>" name="f1">
        <table border="1">
            <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach($paramList as $name => $value) {
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . $name .'" value="' . $value . '">';
            }
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="CHECKSUMHASH" value="<?php echo $checkSum ?>">
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.f1.submit();
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

encdec_paytm.php

```
<?php

function encrypt_e($input, $ky) {
    $key = $ky;
    $size = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 'cbc');
    $input = pkcs5_pad_e($input, $size);
    $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', 'cbc', '');
    $iv = "@@@@&&&&####$$$$";
    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
    $data = mcrypt_generic($td, $input);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);
    $data = base64_encode($data);
    return $data;
}

function decrypt_e($crypt, $ky) {

    $crypt = base64_decode($crypt);
    $key = $ky;
    $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', 'cbc', '');
    $iv = "@@@@&&&&####$$$$";
    mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
    $decrypted_data = mdecrypt_generic($td, $crypt);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
    mcrypt_module_close($td);
    $decrypted_data = pkcs5_unpad_e($decrypted_data);
    $decrypted_data = rtrim($decrypted_data);
    return $decrypted_data;
}

function pkcs5_pad_e($text, $blocksize) {
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}

function pkcs5_unpad_e($text) {
    $pad = ord($text{strlen($text) - 1});
    if ($pad > strlen($text))
        return false;
    return substr($text, 0, -1 * $pad);
}

function generateSalt_e($length) {
    $random = "";
    srand((double) microtime() * 1000000);

    $data = "AbcDE123IJKLMN67QRSTUVWXYZ";
    $data .= "aBCdefghijklmn123opq45rs67tuv89wxyz";
    $data .= "0FGH45OP89";

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $random .= substr($data, (rand() % (strlen($data))), 1);
    }

    return $random;
}

function checkString_e($value) {
    $myvalue = ltrim($value);
    $myvalue = rtrim($myvalue);
    if ($myvalue == 'null')
        $myvalue = '';
    return $myvalue;
}

function getChecksumFromArray($arrayList, $key, $sort=1) {
    if ($sort != 0) {
        ksort($arrayList);
    }
    $str = getArray2Str($arrayList);
    $salt = generateSalt_e(4);
    $finalString = $str . "|" . $salt;
    $hash = hash("sha256", $finalString);
    $hashString = $hash . $salt;
    $checksum = encrypt_e($hashString, $key);
    return $checksum;
}
function getChecksumFromString($str, $key) {

    $salt = generateSalt_e(4);
    $finalString = $str . "|" . $salt;
    $hash = hash("sha256", $finalString);
    $hashString = $hash . $salt;
    $checksum = encrypt_e($hashString, $key);
    return $checksum;
}

function verifychecksum_e($arrayList, $key, $checksumvalue) {
    $arrayList = removeCheckSumParam($arrayList);
    ksort($arrayList);
    $str = getArray2Str($arrayList);
    $paytm_hash = decrypt_e($checksumvalue, $key);
    $salt = substr($paytm_hash, -4);

    $finalString = $str . "|" . $salt;

    $website_hash = hash("sha256", $finalString);
    $website_hash .= $salt;

    $validFlag = "FALSE";
    if ($website_hash == $paytm_hash) {
        $validFlag = "TRUE";
    } else {
        $validFlag = "FALSE";
    }
    return $validFlag;
}

function verifychecksum_eFromStr($str, $key, $checksumvalue) {
    $paytm_hash = decrypt_e($checksumvalue, $key);
    $salt = substr($paytm_hash, -4);

    $finalString = $str . "|" . $salt;

    $website_hash = hash("sha256", $finalString);
    $website_hash .= $salt;

    $validFlag = "FALSE";
    if ($website_hash == $paytm_hash) {
        $validFlag = "TRUE";
    } else {
        $validFlag = "FALSE";
    }
    return $validFlag;
}

function getArray2Str($arrayList) {
    $findme   = 'REFUND';
    $findmepipe = '|';
    $paramStr = "";
    $flag = 1;  
    foreach ($arrayList as $key => $value) {
        $pos = strpos($value, $findme);
        $pospipe = strpos($value, $findmepipe);
        if ($pos !== false || $pospipe !== false) 
        {
            continue;
        }

        if ($flag) {
            $paramStr .= checkString_e($value);
            $flag = 0;
        } else {
            $paramStr .= "|" . checkString_e($value);
        }
    }
    return $paramStr;
}

function redirect2PG($paramList, $key) {
    $hashString = getchecksumFromArray($paramList);
    $checksum = encrypt_e($hashString, $key);
}

function removeCheckSumParam($arrayList) {
    if (isset($arrayList["CHECKSUMHASH"])) {
        unset($arrayList["CHECKSUMHASH"]);
    }
    return $arrayList;
}

function getTxnStatus($requestParamList) {
    return callAPI(PAYTM_STATUS_QUERY_URL, $requestParamList);
}

function getTxnStatusNew($requestParamList) {
    return callNewAPI(PAYTM_STATUS_QUERY_NEW_URL, $requestParamList);
}

function initiateTxnRefund($requestParamList) {
    $CHECKSUM = getChecksumFromArray($requestParamList,PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY);
    $requestParamList["CHECKSUM"] = urlencode($CHECKSUM);
    return callAPI(PAYTM_REFUND_URL, $requestParamList);
}

function callAPI($apiURL, $requestParamList) {
    $jsonResponse = "";
    $responseParamList = array();
    $JsonData =json_encode($requestParamList);
    $postData = 'JsonData='.$JsonData;
    $ch = curl_init($apiURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                         
    'Content-Type: application/json', 
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($postData))                                                                       
    );  
    $jsonResponse = curl_exec($ch);   
    $responseParamList = json_decode($jsonResponse,true);
    return $responseParamList;
}

function callNewAPI($apiURL, $requestParamList) {
    $jsonResponse = "";
    $responseParamList = array();
    $JsonData =json_encode($requestParamList);
    $postData = 'JsonData='.urlencode($JsonData);
    $ch = curl_init($apiURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                         
    'Content-Type: application/json', 
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($postData))                                                                       
    );  
    $jsonResponse = curl_exec($ch);   
    $responseParamList = json_decode($jsonResponse,true);
    return $responseParamList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check whether mcrypt installed in your server. In 90% of the cases – php-mcrypt will already be installed and enabled.

Otherwise enable mcrypt in your server.

Unix Servers:

Given that each server  configuration is somewhat unique, it’s hard to provide instructions for each server, however – php-mcrypt is a php extension which can be installed using apt-get or yum install (if you are using unix server).

CentOS: yum install php-mcrypt OR yum install php5-mcrypt

Debian/Ubuntu: apt-get install php-mcrypt OR apt-get install php5-mcrypt

Once installed, make sure to restart apache/web server.

/etc/init.d/apache restart OR httpd service restart

That should take care of it.